# Is the C++ expression for_each(v, [](string x) syntactically correct?

Tags: c++, lambda, cpp-core-guidelines

Is the below expression valid for `for_each()`?

```
for_each(v,[](string x){
    cout<<x<<endl;
});
```

Ref: [CppCoreGuidelines.md#p3-express-intent](https://github.com/isocpp/CppCoreGuidelines/blob/master/CppCoreGuidelines.md#p3-express-intent)

The above expression throws below error:

> ```
> error: no matching function for call to ‘for_each(std::vector<std::__cxx11::basic_string<char> >&,
> main()::<lambda(std::__cxx11::string)>)’
>      });
>       ^
> In file included from /usr/include/c++/5/algorithm:62:0,
>                  from test.cpp:4:
> /usr/include/c++/5/bits/stl_algo.h:3761:5: note: candidate: template<class _IIter, class _Funct> _Funct std::for_each(_IIter,
> _IIter, _Funct)
>      for_each(_InputIterator __first, _InputIterator __last, _Function __f)
>      ^
> /usr/include/c++/5/bits/stl_algo.h:3761:5: note:   template argument deduction/substitution failed:
> test.cpp:60:6: note:   deduced conflicting types for parameter ‘_IIter’ (‘std::vector<std::__cxx11::basic_string<char> >’ and
> ‘main()::<lambda(std::__cxx11::string)>’)
>      });
> ```

Comment: No, it is not..

Comment: They could be using the [ranges TS](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/experimental/ranges) `for_each`.

Comment: can you elaborate your code? it's ambiguous which for_each you refere to

Comment: I removed the [c++11] tag because the guidelines refer to the current version of the standard and they clearly say that this example is based on the Ranges TS.

Answer (score 3):

Well, the Core Guidelines mention `for_each`, not `std::for_each`. So it's hard to answer your question...

- If they are actually referring to `std::for_each`, then it would be a typo, as it requires two iterators - unless they're referring to a future version of [`std::for_each` that might be introduced with the Ranges proposals](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/experimental/ranges#Algorithms).
- If they are referring to a generic `for_each`, then it could simply be:

  ```
  template <typename TContainer, typename TF>
  void for_each(TContainer&& c, TF&& f)
  {
      for(auto&& x : c) f(x);
  }
  ```

Comment: The guidelines say "This example uses the for_each from the Ranges TS because it directly expresses the intent:". The guidelines normally don't write "std::" (search for cin or other identifiers in std namespace).